# I wanted to automate the model and route parts in node.js express

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, automation, frameworks

I wanted to automate the model and route parts in node.js express.
For example, the index.js of routes originally looked like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('index', {title:'Express' });
});

router.get('/a1', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('a1', {title:'Repetitive router.get' });
});

router.get('/a2', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('a2', {title:'Repetitive router.get' });
});

router.get('/a3', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('a3', {title:'Repetitive router.get' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I don’t want to hard-code this every time
router.get function part

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var AAA = require('myGetAll');

AAA.add('/a1', a1, {title:'Repetitive router.get' });
AAA.add('/a2', a2, {title:'Repetitive router.get' });
AAA.add('/a3', a3, {title:'Repetitive router.get' });

/* GET home page. */
for(let i = 0; i <AAA.count(); i++){
    router.get(AAA.itemPath[i], function(req, res, next) {
      res.render(AAA.itemFile[i], AAA.itemParameter[i]);
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

I would like to do it this way.
Would it be okay to do this?

if not
MVC like express, but
Recommend a framework with better code automation.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific so I might be able to help you better? As in "I don’t want to hardcode this every time router.get function part" what do you mean by that?

Comment: I have to do the code below over and over again.
Like config. It would be convenient to read it like this and load it at once.

I have to do the same code every time,
If the route needs to change, you will eventually have to touch the js file.
This makes it difficult to automate.

"router.get"

Comment: I want to reduce the code being compiled.
I want code that can change data fluidly like ini and json files.

However, "router.get", "app.set", and these statements require you to enter the code unconditionally.

I learned these codes as "hard-code" in the South-Korea.
I don't know how to express it in English. I wrote using google-translator.

Comment: I haven't heard of a way to do what you're asking specifically. However, I would advise that you write it all out and hard code it as it makes it easier to debug in the long run. That's my opinion but I hope somebody can help with a solution to your problem.

Comment: You are right.
I think it would be comfortable to use it like this.
Most of the samples are fixed and you have to express yourself
I was asking if there was another way.

Anyway, thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good way you could achieve this using route params.

```
router.get('/:param(a+[1-3])', function(req, res, next) {
   const parameter = req.params.param;
   res.render(parameter, {title:`Repetitive router.get this ${parameter}` });
});
```

You can pass an optional regular expression to the route to match the desired param, or just handle the input inside your code logic (in this case i´ve added a regex to match a1-a3)

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: I am glad you answered.
I am going to test your method.